# Pattern for activity that starts another activity (for result)

Tags: android

I have an activity where the first thing it does is start another activity for result. when the result comes back, it should process it, then finish. I have the `startActivityForResult()` call in `onCreate()`.

What I see is that *sometimes* when I return from the target activity i started, `onCreate()` in my activity is called again. this of course re-starts the target activity a second time.

This makes sense and I understand why this is the case, but I don't understand the correct pattern for what I'm trying to achieve. When I return from the activity i started, i don't want to re-start the target activity again obviously ... I just want to run `onActivityResult()` and finish.

I read where someone suggested setting a state preference, but that seems like a good source for bugs, for example, if it got stuck in the wrong state.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not process the result in the first activity, rather than going to another? Or are you using it as some sort of factory?

Comment: I think your design pattern is flawed here.  Why do you need an activity that doesn't interact with the user and just processes results.  Sounds like you need a service.

Comment: i don't have control over the second activity.

Comment: let me provide a simple example ... an activity that scans a barcode then shows the user the contents. i want to re-use the zxing intent-based mechanism for capturing the barcode.

Comment: can't you have a member that you save on `onSaveInstanceState` (changed once you've called the other activity)? You could check in your onCreate the status of this var in the passed Bundle to see if you have to start the other activity or not...

Comment: thanks damp ... here's what i am worried about. user starts my activity, i set the bundle flag, then they are off in activity 2. now they press "home" because they decide they want to abort. now they access my activity again. is the flag still set? it should not be. also i want to cancel the flag in onActivityResult(), but i do not have access to the saved bundle there. the other problem is that onCreate() is only called *sometimes*, so you can't do something like toggle the state on onCreate().

Comment: That isn't how the activity lifecycle was really built to work. If the user presses home, they should be able to click on your app again, and start where they left off. If you want to do something different, you need to implement that functionality in the onPause/onDestroy/onResume/etc etc methods.

Comment: hence my question. how to achieve this use case.

Comment: @farble1670: I don't think you've explained a very detailed use case. What's the use case exactly? I think you should go back through the activity lifecycle documentation.

Comment: activity A listens for SEND intent. when it's received, the first thing it does is grab content from a barcode. it then "processes" the contents of the barcode. there's no activity in front of my activity, so i can't "remove the middle man" as suggested in several places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to start the target activity in `onResume()`, not `onCreate()`. From the javadocs on `onActivityResult()`,

> You will receive this call immediately
> before onResume() when your activity
> is re-starting.

In other words, you can be assured that `onActivityResult()` is called before `onResume()` ... So for example, set a flag that says "don't start target activity this time" in `onActivityResult()` so when `onResume()` is subsequently called, you can avoid re-starting the target activity.